# Ocaml Functional Programming Tree

Tags: ocaml

I'm writing a function called unzip that turns:

```
[(1,2);(3,4);(5,6)]
```

to

```
([1;3;5],[2;4;6])
```

I've got a working implementation right here:

```
let unzip (data:(int*int) list) : int list * int list =
   match data with
   |(x,y)::tl->(x::traverse (tl,true),y::traverse (tl,false))
   |[]->([],[])
  let rec traverse tree = 
    match tree with
    |((x,y)::tl,dir) -> if dir then x::traverse (tl, dir) else y::traverse (tl,dir)
    |([],_) -> [];;
```

However I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way to do this. As you can see, my traverse function accepts a boolean to know whether or not to go right or left, specifically because of:

```
(x::traverse (tl,true),y::traverse (tl,false))
```

Now is there even a way to do this so I only have to call one function, AND it knows where to put the data? or is this an alright way of doing it?

PS: I can't use non-core functions. (Modules, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you didn't quite know how to get there.  You don't need that `traverse` function to operate on the left or right lists.  Just bind them to separate variables through a simple `let in` expression and you can add the items to each of the lists.

```
let rec unzip = function
    | (x, y)::t -> let l, r = unzip t in (x::l, y::r)
    | []        -> ([], [])
```

Comment: Why is its syntax so weird lol. Anyway, thank you very much!